# Cant connect orange to local PGSQL server

Tags: postgresql, orange

I installed Orange and I have data in a local PGSQL server.

PGSQL listens on the default port which is 5432.

I have the psycopg2 lib installed, and I also wrote a short python script which pulls some data from the database to check the module is insatlled correctly.

Firewall is down.

Python Env Path is set to use 3.4.4 which is what Orange3 uses.

When I add a sql table widget, I get an error suggesting "please install a backend to use this widgt"

Documentaion in Orange site mentions that all that needs to be done for the DB integration is just installing the python module, but this doesnt work for me.

Help would be appreciated.

Links:
https://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/visual-programming/widgets/data/sqltable.html